# How can I convert security logs to a Knowledge Graph?

Tags: parsing, logging, neo4j, nlp, graph-databases

Given a set of logs from AWS, GCP, Azure and system/services logs, I would like to convert them to a knowledge graph.
I have researched that there are some partial solutions (and very old) for doing similar tasks - [Slogert](https://github.com/sepses/slogert), [LEKG](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3502223.3502250) and [VloGraph](https://www.mdpi.com/2504-4990/4/2/16/pdf)

Any best practices doing it? Any known repo or solution?

Comment: Hello, it would be helpful if you can add a bit more to the question. What have you tried so far? What issues did you find with those approaches? Otherwise, the question requires a subjective (opinion based) answer, and those tend to get closed by moderators. I see the question already has one vote to close it. What questions are you looking for this knowledges graph to answer? Have you thought about how you might model the data to best get those answers? Have you considered different graph technology approaches?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence thanks for your comment :)
I am trying to build a graph out of logs, for example you get a log from your cloud ec2 instance or from Azure or from your service. I want to build the relevant triplets of what affected what and how.

Comment: @SteveS have you been able to solve this problem.  If yes how?

Comment: @Alchemist we've used ETL to do this and load it to the graph + some graphGPT solutions.